# Geoserver not displaying ArcSDE versioned table data as it is updated

Tags: geoserver, enterprise-geodatabase

Has anybody managed to get GeoServer 2.8 with the ArcSDE plugin (ArcSDE 10.0) to retrieve updates to data as soon as they are made when data is retrieved from a SDE view?

The SDE view is in Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 which is based on a versioned feature class that takes part in a replica, hence can not use the 'move edits to base' option.

If any features are added/edited/deleted in the database they are posted back to the SDE.DEFAULT version. But GeoServer does not display the correct data unless it is restarted or the catalog is reloaded.  It seems that it keeps querying the data at the point it makes its first connection.

I am aware the edits are stored in delta tables and not the base table.  GeoServer only has access it would seem to the base table.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a [versioned view](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//006z0000000q000000)?

Comment: Restarting the Geoserver service should not have any impact; only a reconcile and post will transfer the  delta records to the base table.